# Showing Tkinter window larger than desktop

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I need to show Tkinter window, which I create with Tk(), to be larger than desktop, and moved to some coordinates outside the desktop.

Unfortunately when I do:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d", (10000, 10000, -300, -300))
```

then this window shows up, but maximized on desktop.

When I show the window at first, and resize/move later, then everything is OK, but I don't want to see the small empty window at the beginning.

How can I show the window with the coordinates and size at the very beginning?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
from Tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()

root.withdraw()
root.update_idletasks()

root.geometry("+-1000+-1000")
root.minsize(2000, 2000)

root.deiconify()

root.mainloop()
```

`withdraw` hides the window, `deiconify` shows it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. it works, but not fully. The window is bigger than the screen, however the left upper corner is exactly in the left upper corner. The window is not moved to (-1000,-1000), but rather to (0,0).

Comment: Hm, looks like the behavior is different on different operating systems. For example, it works on my ubuntu 12.04. In the question you noted that you've found the way to move the window, could you insert the code for moving the window between `withdraw/deiconify`?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. Setting position before mainloop() doesn't work. It works only when I move window which is shown up.

Comment: Could you please show how do you move the window after the `mainloop` call?

Comment: This can move window outside desktop: https://gist.github.com/szymong/3d56488f7663bc3e8db3

Comment: Thank you! Interesting, now I have the same problem you had with my code: The window is bigger than the screen, however the left upper corner is exactly in the left upper corner. :)

Comment: I've found a workaround to my problem, I can create a window smaller than desktop. This solves my problem, however it doesn't solve problem with Tk.

Comment: Might be the window manager refusing to honor the polite request to have a very large window. Which would explain why it doesn't work on some systems despite working on others…