# How to move a program window to -x -y? Multi platform solution required

Tags: python, window, screen

I am trying to make a window on Ubuntu 13.10 slide in from the left or top.
I have tried using tkinter in python, as well as Xdotool which is a command line tool which uses X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions

It seems as from the comments in the link i posted below, that people are getting different functionality based on there windows managers.

I know that on my system the window cannot be maximized for me to change the position of windows, and even then i am still unable to move it off the left or top side of the screen.

How do i get past these restrictions?
If anyone could give some ideas of what i need to look for and where i can find it that would be great.

Ref -> [Showing Tkinter window larger than desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327678/showing-tkinter-window-larger-than-desktop)

Comment: Have you considered expanding the size of the window, starting from 0 and stopping when the required size is met, to give the illusion of the window moving? Here's some documentation that could help you set that up for Tkinter: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm

Comment: which window are you referring to? I would like the window size to remain the same

Comment: The root window, I guess. Make it expand until it reaches the size of a Frame that holds all of the widgets? Just an alternative, if you can't move a window off-screen.